# Class html not found in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to upload an image from my 'public/uploads/' folder.But whenever i run the page i get the following error.I am using 5.2

> Class HTML not found

How i can remove this error?

```
@extends('main')

@section('content')

<h1>This is show.blade.php</h1>

    @if(isset($info))
    <div class='col-md-2 col-md-offset-2'>
        {{HTML::image('uploads/zami.jpg')}}
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
           <span>user id :</span><span>{{$info['info']['id']}}</span></br>
           <span>username :</span><span>{{$info['info']['username']}}</span></br>
    </div>
   @endif
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in composer.json require section

`"illuminate/html": "5.*"`

and run composer update

Open your `config/app.php`

add under 'providers' array add this

`Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,`

add under 'aliases' array add this

```
'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

and under your blade templates, use like this

`{!! Html::image('uploads/zami.jpg') !!}`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i have "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*" in my composer.json  and in "providers" section i have "Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class" and in "aliases" section i have  "'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,"

Comment: should i change them...my form works in my application ?

Comment: Yes, you can use this also for Laravel 5.2, but you can also use the `"illuminate/html": "5.*"`.

Comment: if i can use this and my Form works just fine then why not "html" class not working and giving me error?

Comment: DId you add namespace in your blade file?

Comment: i found the problem..it should be "Html" not "HTML" ..thanks for your time anyway :)

Comment: Yes Al-zami, If you are happy with my answer and got solution so please accept this answer so anyone can use this.

Comment: can you edit your final section of your post ."HTML" to "Html" ?

Answer (score 1):

By default in Laravel 5.0, Html and Form are not embedded anymore.

Add the following line `"illuminate/html": "5.*"` in the require section of `composer.json` file and run `composer update`

Register the service provider in `config/app.php` by adding the following value into the providers array: `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider`

Register facades by adding these two lines in the aliases array:

```
'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'
```

Comment: i have "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*" in my composer.json and in "providers" section i have "Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class" and in "aliases" section i have "'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class, 'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,"

Comment: should i change them...my form works in my application ?
 
i followed this link laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html

Comment: Try running `php artisan dump-autoload` and see if it's working

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Laravel Collective` installed, try to use:

```
{!! Html::image !!}
```

Instead of:

```
{{ Html::image }}
```

Comment: Thanks .. the problem was in upper case "HTML" keyword